# Dictionary of dataflow programming terms

Tags: java, .net, asynchronous, actor, dataflow

I am developing a dataflow library for java, and I would like to give names to classes as  it is customary to computer science. For example, I have following dataflow construct:

it has 2 input queues, one for messages and one for actors (actors in sense of the Actor computing model).

whenever both queues are not empty, take the next message and send it to the next actor; remove both message and actor from the queue.

I would like to know if a traditional term for such a construct exists, and better yet, if there is a dictionary with all dataflow terms.

Answer (score 1):

Usually there's just a queue of messages/tasks/work. The workers are pooled (rather than queued) and they just grab work off the queue as they become available to do the work. It doesn't usually matter which worker grabs the work. I'd call that "work queue" or "task queue" or something like that.

If it really does matter in your case that certain workers do the work before other ones, then sorry, don't know the answer to that. :-)

Comment: in this case, workers are actors and cannot actively "grab work off the queue" - this may block them, which is not allowed. So this double queue is an active object.